# How to display foreach loop values of php in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, bootstrap-5

I have a php foreach loop which display values perfectly but when i try to display them in modal it only shows either first or last record value. I want modal to display value of the record i click on

i tried clicking on modal but it only displayed last record of the loop

```
<?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>  
    <div class="card-body">
        <h2 class="fw-light text-center"><?php echo ($row['vbrandname'])?></h2>
        <p class="card-text"><?php echo ($row['vaboutbrand'])?></p>
        <p class="card-text"><?php echo ($row['vwebsitelink'])?></p>
        <p class="card-text"><?php echo ($row['contactemail'])?></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModalmail2brand">
                Email
        </button>
    </div>
 <?php } ?>  







        <div class="modal fade" id="myModalmail2brand" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel">Send Mail to Brand</h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <form class="form-inline" action="" method="post" >
                    <div class="mb-3">
                      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="form-label">Your Email address</label>
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                      <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1" class="form-label">Your Query</label>
                      <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" required name="remember" value="" id="flexCheckDefault">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault">Confirm Your Data</label>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" name="submitmail2brand" class="btn btn-primary" >Send</button>
                  </form>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Discard</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code, please.

Comment: I have just updated code..sorry i misssed earlier

Comment: Looks like you are generating multiple buttons to trigger a modal in your loop now - but only _one_ modal, after the loop? How would you expect this to work then? You either need one individual modal per button; or you need to store the relevant data on the button (custom data attributes), and then write some additional JS logic to populate the fields in one single modal, with the correct data each time.